# xcode 10.0 on Macports

Tags: xcode, macports, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am new to using Macports to download software I have just upgraded to Mojave and have made sure I have the latest versions of both Macports and Xcode command line tools. I have been getting the message

`Warning: xcodebuild exists but failed to execute`

when trying to download gnuradio. I then used 'port diagnose' and received the following message:

`Error: currently installed version of Xcode, none, is not supported by MacPorts.  For your currently installed system, only the following versions of Xcode are supported:  10.0`

This is despite the fact that I am using xcode 10.0 and have never run anything earlier than that. Am I missing something or could it be that Mojave hasn't been available for long enough for possible bugs to be solved with the programs. If anybody has an alternate way of running gnuradio-companion i'd be happy to hear. I have already tried via home-brew but ran into problems with that as well.

Thanks for your help,

Arthur

Answer (score 1):

@Wallace Huang's answer worked for me (Mojave 10.14.6):

1. Open Xcode
2. Select Preferences -> Locations
3. Command Line Tools version gives a drop down menu and I was able to select the single option for which version of Command Line tools I have.

[Screen shot of Xcode Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiWtV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 10, go to Preferences, select Locations tab, and choose a version in Command Line Tools. On a fresh install, this field is blank (hence your version is "none").